# How to debug "host not found in upstream app_server"?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I created a fresh django (digitalocean) droplet on ubuntu 14.04, pointed my domain registrar to the DO nameservers, used sslmate to purchase and store the relevant ssl files on the server, and updated the nginx config file as necessary.

When I try to start (or restart) nginx, in /var/log/nginx/error.log I get:

```
[emerg] 1656#0: host not found in upstream "app_server" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django:56
```

I'm not sure how to debug this, and I haven't found anything useful by googling.  I'm not even sure what the error message is referring to.  Any idea where I should start?

Here's the entire config file:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
    rewrite ^ https://domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    listen 443 ssl;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name domain.com;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/sslmate/www.domain.com.key;
    ssl_certificate /etc/sslmate/www.domain.com.chained.crt;

    # Recommended security settings from https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /usr/share/sslmate/dhparams/dh2048-group14.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
    # Enable this if you want HSTS (recommended)
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have an `upstream app_server` defined!

Comment: Ugh I just saw it too :( "app_" should be "app_server" on the first line.